# Json Decode Php,Get The name using the ID

Tags: json, string, get

I got this json,and I dont know how to get the name,by knowing the ID.

```
[
    { "id":0, "name":"N/A"  },
    { "id":1, "name":"John" },
    { "id":2, "name":"Doom" }
]
```

I am trying to :

```
$json= file_get_contents($json);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

but I dunno what to do next.. :(

Comment: `var_dump( $data )` and take some time to figure it out. Use `foreach`.

Answer (score 0):

just include underscore.js and do somenthing like

```
_.each(json, function(datum){ 
   if ( yourid === datum.id ) { //yourcode } 
});
```

Comment: Sorry,I cannot understand...
All I want is to call the json with an ID,and the json to return the name of this ID mate...